# Replacing older netgear router with new netgear router

Tags: installation

Dell desktop running windows 7.  Using older netgear router, want to remove that router and install new netgear router.  Any special instructions?

Answer (score 1):

If your router is connected to a cable modem or similar that relies on DHCP IP leases then you may need to power cycle your modem as well. This is often a skipped step as people don't understand how the devices communicate and establish connection with a new device is present. This isn't the case for computers added to the network through the router as they should automatically pick up new leases.

1. Unplug Modem
2. Hook up new router. Should be same plug ins as the old one. Leave power cord alone for now.
3. Plug power into modem.
4. Wait for a minute until all lights are solid.
5. Plug power into router
6. Wait for router to boot up
7. Secure/Lock Down wireless to prevent unauthorized access.

For step 7, refer to your user manual. Typically this is done using a web interface on a device plugged into the router. You can do this using a WiFi computer, but often suggested to use one locally (attached via ethernet cable). Netgear routers often have a default username and password of admin/admin. Their default ip address is often either 192.168.1.1 or 192.168.0.1.

If these steps do not work, then you may need to call your ISP to let them know that you've attached a new device. However, this is often not the case.

If you are using DSL which requires device authentication, then you will need to skip to step 7 and also plug in some authentication credentials.

Comment: Would like to add that "default ip address" could be different from your old router. Instead of 192.168.0.1 it could be 10.0.0.1. Compare your old router ip address to the default to be sure. If different change your new router ip address to your old thru the web interface.